# PHP Curl file download has 0 bytes when using ajax?

Tags: php, curl

I'm having trouble downloading a file with curl via ajax.  When i load the `curl.php` file without ajax the file downloads to server, the full file is downloaded.  When i use ajax to call `curl.php` the file appears in the server folder but it has zero bytes.

curl.php

```
$link = "http://www.example.com/wp-content/my_channels/".$_POST['download_link'];
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];


    $destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/my_channels/videos/".$filename.".mp4";


    $file = fopen($destination, 'w');
    // cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
    // set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // set file handler option
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
    // execute cURL
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // close cURL
    curl_close($ch);
    // close file
    fclose($file);

    if($result) {
        echo 1;
    }
```

How do i solve?

ajax

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/wp-content/my_channels/curl.php";
        var data = {
          filename:filename,
          download_link:download_link
        };

jQuery.post(url,data,function(response) {

});
```

I get these three errors

> **Warning**: 
>   fopen(/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/my_channels/videos/لخ
>   ترین مراسم ختمی که تا به حال دیده اشتباه والدین،کودک 4 ماه را به خواب
>   ابدی برد!.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/my_channels/curl.php** on
>   line **33**
>  
>  **Warning**:  curl_setopt(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in
>   **/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/my_channels/curl.php** on
>   line **42**
>  
>  **Warning**:  fclose() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   **/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/my_channels/curl.php** on
>   line **49**
>   **

Comment: how do you post your ajax?

Comment: Any output from curl_error($ch) ?

Comment: @hassan check edit

Comment: `console.log(data)` and see, also check if there is any other errors in your console

Comment: check edit, i've included errors.  This works when i load `curl.php` in the browser.